# Makefile: How to write a pattern rule with prerequisite without suffix

Tags: makefile

In embedded projects you typically convert an ELF output from gcc into a raw binary form with objcopy. I tried to write a pattern rule for that: `%.bin: %` (executable output from gcc doesn't have a suffix, at least on Linux). This fails with `make: *** No rule to make target ...`

Here is a complete test case:

test.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
%.bin: %
    objcopy -O binary $< $@
```

This works by saying `make test test.bin`, that is, by explicitly asking it to build `test` executable first. It does not work by saying `make test.bin`. Somehow in that case make does not realize it can make prerequisite with a built in rule.

I know I can fix this by writing the rule as `test.bin: test` but I'd like to know, why this pattern rule does not work and can I make it work somehow.

Furthermore, I think the obvious and practical ways to make it work breaks the nice and elegant built in rule system. It could be rescued if I could put an option into e.g. LDFLAGS to make linker output the executable with some suffix e.g. `.elf` (do I still have to rewrite the built in rule for linking? Oh well...).

I admit, this is purely academic problem born in pedantic mind.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is correct, but you hit a caveat of make -- make will not chain pure `%` targets with other implicit rules --

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules

> ... for performance reasons make will not consider non-terminal
> match-anything rules (i.e., ‘%:’) when searching for a rule to build a
> prerequisite of an implicit rule (see Match-Anything Rules).

Comment: Ok, I have read that text but didn't think it would apply here, because '%' is in the prerequisite side. But now that I think about it second time, it starts to make sense. Then, I wonder, how is the built in rule for linking written? It has to be treated internally in a special way, hasn't it?

Comment: "when searching for a rule to build a prerequisite of an implicit rule" -- in the case of `make test`, `test` is not a prerequisite of an implicit rule, so it can match the linking target.    If, on the other hand you do `make test.bin`, then `test` _is_ a prerequisite of an implicit target, and therefore make will not search for `%`

Comment: And with that you are saying that actually the built in linking rule is **not** getting any special treatment? Yes, this all has been in the documentation all the time. For some reason I've had hard time to digest it.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an executable output with a suffix in gcc by passing the output `-o` option with the name and extension.
Example:

```
# Give your elf file name
ELF_FILE= test.elf 

$(ELF_FILE): $(OBJ_FILES)
    echo "Creating elf file"
    gcc.exe -o $(ELF_FILE) $(OBJ_FILES)

%.bin: %.elf
    objcopy -O binary $< $@
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is obviously a good practical solution but, thinking in pedantic way, it has the down side of rewriting the built in rule. I was searching for a way to convince make that it can use the built in rule to make 'test'. I'm beginning to believe that there is no such way.

Answer (score 0):

My example works when running make like this: `make test test.bin` because, IIUC, `test` is built first and then the prerequisite is already there for building `test.bin`. Exploiting that, I modified the Makefile like this:

```
all: $(subst .bin, , $(filter %.bin, $(MAKECMDGOALS))) $(MAKECMDGOALS)

%.bin: %
    objcopy -O binary $< $@
```

Now I can run `make test.bin` and make builds first test and then test.bin. Or I can run `make foo bar.bin` and make tries to build foo, bar and bar.bin. This is the closest thing I can come up with. On the positive side is that the Makefile does not have to reference explicitly any file names and no built in rules are rewritten.